# CORB writing less files in CSV?

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-corb

I am running CORB for converting my data to CSV . When i am running with `THREAD-COUNT-1` it is working perfectly fine means i am getting all the file outputs in CSV file. But when i increased the thread-size and Batch-size it is showing less number of output files in my CSV file. I dont know why?

Below is my Properties file

```
THREAD-COUNT=5
BATCH-SIZE=10
URIS-MODULE=selector.sjs|ADHOC
PROCESS-MODULE=transform.sjs|ADHOC
PROCESS-TASK=com.marklogic.developer.corb.ExportBatchToFileTask
EXPORT-FILE-NAME=HelloWorldReport.csv
PRE-BATCH-TASK=com.marklogic.developer.corb.PreBatchUpdateFileTask
EXPORT-FILE-TOP-CONTENT=a,b,c,d,e,uri
```

But in the CORB command prompt i can see all the uris . But when writing into CSV it is returing only few.

I had followed [this documentation](https://github.com/marklogic-community/corb2/wiki/JavaScript-Modules) for setting up my selector and transform module. Below is my selector.sjs module

```
var total = cts.uris("", null, cts.collectionQuery("data"));
fn.insertBefore(total,0,fn.count(total))
```

In my transform.sjs i am getting elements from my documents and then i am concatenating them

```
var name = fn.tokenize(URI, ";");
for ( var uri of name) {
let obj = fn.head(fn.doc(uri)).toObject();
var a = obj.Name;
var b = obj.Country;
var c = obj.State;
var d = obj.Code;
var e = obj.University;
fn.concat(a,b,c,d,e,uri);
}
```

And also is there any function in Marklogic for keeping a delimiter in between values(i.e.Means in the above `fn.concat` i am concatenating all the strings(abcdeuri) but what i want is to delimit each of them with `,`(a,b,c,d,e,uri). I tried using`fn.stringJoin` but i can't send more than three values into it )

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that [only the last evaluated expression is returned from a JavaScript module](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48367169/14419). You are generating strings inside of the for loop, so when you set the **BATCH-SIZE** greater than 1, only the last item from your for loop is being returned.

You could increase your **THREAD-COUNT** and keep the **BATCH-SIZE**=1 and should get the desired output without changing the process module.

In order for your process module to return the desired results with a **BATCH-SIZE** greater than 1, you need to collect the results as you process the data inside of your for loop, and then return all of the data outside of the for loop. You can collect the data by pushing into an Array variable and then return a Sequence of strings using [Sequence.from()](https://docs.marklogic.com/Sequence.from).

You can use the [fn.stringJoin()](https://docs.marklogic.com/fn.stringJoin) function to produce a CSV. The first parameter is the sequence of values, which you can put into an array, and the second parameter is the value to join with.

```
var URI;
var name = fn.tokenize(URI, ";");
var results = [];
for ( var uri of name) {
let obj = fn.head(fn.doc(uri)).toObject();
var a = obj.Name;
var b = obj.Country;
var c = obj.State;
var d = obj.Code;
var e = obj.University;
results.push(fn.stringJoin([a,b,c,d,e,uri], ","));
}
Sequence.from(results);
```

Comment: Thanks @Hansen, i can able to achieve the same by declaring `const Node ` and extracting with xpath like this `var a= node.xpath("/Name");` . Is there any performance tradeoff's for these two ways ?

Comment: I don't know that you will see a significant difference either way, especially if your docs are rather small. Profiling and timing an individual process module execution may not reveal much of a difference. The easiest way to find out is probably to run the CORB jobs both ways and see if either way happens to perform any better.

Comment: I also would like to  point out that the asker also has an example already where much of this (including the use of the outer string join and further explanations in comments is here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48629176/traversing-a-json-node-using-javascript-in-marklogic/48634138